# The protocol field for curl is empty

Tags: http, curl, libcurl, openvms

I tried to build my own curllib.olb for openVMS with source 7.47.1 and using the build_vms.com script provided here: https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/packages/vms/build_vms.com

The build goes fine. However, the protocol field seems to be empty:

```
   > curl --version
```

I get:

```
 curl 7.47.1 (unknown) libcurl/7.47.1
 Protocols:
 Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

There are no protocols in the suppported protocols list. Is this the default behavior or did I miss something obvious that I needed to set?

I see that there are options to set it: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS.html

but a little confused about where to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it shows all protocols it was built to support (see [curl/lib/version.c](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/version.c#L187)). By default libcurl supports a busload of protocols and a slew more if it has the correct 3rd party libs to use...

At build time you can however disable specific protocols so it looks like your build is actively disabling all the protocols.

Comment: Thanks. The options were disabled in the curl_config.h file.